# GCC: Getting the correct function addresses from the .symtab segment

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, powerpc

I have written a backtrace dump routine for my embedded C program.  But I am having trouble with reading the .symtab segment.

When I read .symtab, the function addresses are close, but incorrect.  They are not off by a fixed offset, it varies.  And by "off", I mean they don't match the actual function address in the C program, and don't match the map file.  There are off by anywhere from 0 to about 0x1200 bytes, that I have noticed.

This is for an embedded project, so I don't have access to dlopen.  This is for gcc 4.1.1, for a PowerPC 405 processor.  This is an old project that I am maintaining.

My flags when building C files are:
-O1 -Winline -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing 
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -g

My flags when linking are:
-O1 -Winline -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing 
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -g 
-Wl,-Map,map.txt  -Wl,-T -Wl,linker_script.ld

I have also tried -gstabs.

There is no relocation going on -- the program is statically linked with the correct RAM addresses already set up.  To load it I just copy it into RAM and jump to crt_init.

Does anyone know why the .symtab addresses are wrong by seemingly random small offsets?  Is there another lookup up table in the .elf file that I need to consult?

Thank you.

Comment: Have the addresses in the symbol-table generated by the linker the same offset? (ld -M [object-file])

Comment: I think you mean the map file (which -M produces), not symbol table.  The map file addresses are correct and match the actual location of functions in memory

Comment: Does your target have function descriptors? Are there any `.opd` sections?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by function descriptors.  There are no .opd sections.